# Any good guides to learning FLASM (Flash bytecode)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, optimization, compiler-construction, bytecode

Flash has been a long-standing industry standard for interactive web content. Still, it's also known for being damn slow and inefficient. So in the same vein that knowing ASM will help you write better C++, knowing [FLASM](http://www.nowrap.de/flasm.html) will improve your actionscript.

Does anyone know any good resource for learning this, or should I just disassemble and assemble until I get it?

Thank you.

Comment: If written following best-practices, it's definitely not slow and inefficient. It's like anything, a hammer does not a carpenter make.

Comment: JPEA, please see: http://jpauclair.net/2010/03/15/flash-asm/ If you think the recommended optimization here ought to be "best practices"...

Comment: my apologies - I thought this was a troll post, considering the beating Flash takes with people who hate unoptimized banner ads - I didn't realize you'd actually get into the meat n' potatoes of it :)

Comment: Unoptimized banner ads are indeed the scourge of all browsers that use Flash without some form of adblock. ("Hey I have over 10 tabs open." <- You're screwed.) But yeah, Flash has issues and needs some awkward hand-holding sometimes, so I'm asking to get into the details. :-)

Comment: Do you know the AVM2 Overview? http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf  I think it's a good place to start.

Comment: Hey, why not post it as an answer? You'd get points. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Do you know the [AVM2 Overview](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf)? I think it's a good place to start.